# Finding the pH of the resultant solution when a pH1 solution mixed with a pH2 solution

Tags: ph, mixtures

I want to know that is it possible that a $\mathrm{pH_1}$ solution mixed with a $\mathrm{pH_2}$ solution and the mixture would be less than $\mathrm{pH_1}$?

Is it possible that the result has a lower $\mathrm{pH}$ value than the original solutions?

Comment: Strictly speaking no, you can write a free-energy diagram which would show that this is impossible. However, if the addition of the second solution somehow reacted to create a new compound that was less acidic then this could be possible.

Comment: And what is "PH2 solution "?

Comment: And it spells **pH**, not PH or ph.

Answer (score 2):

If you have equal volumes of Solution A containing 0.01 M $\ce{HCl}$ and 0.1 M $\ce{BaCl2}$ and solution B containing 0.1 M apiece $\ce{Na2SO4}$ and $\ce{NaHSO4}$, each one has a pH of 2 or nearly so (based on the Henderson-Hasselbach Equation for B).  If you now mix them the barium ions from A selectively precipitate the sulfate ions rather than the bisulfate ions from B, forcing the latter to dissociate and the pH will drop below its initial value of 2.

Comment: Never answer a question with a negative score, maybe?

Comment: I upvoted both answers. Unfortunately, I seem to fall into the “answer questions with negative scores” pit on a regular basis. I am frequently surprised at what does not find favor.

Comment: I did so with the other answer.  @ed if you know me on this site you probably recognize that when I detect downvotes and no constructive criticism, I squawk.  Yup this is one of those squawks.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not ! If a saturated NaCl solution is added to an equal volume of $\ce{HCl}$ $0.01$ M, the pH goes from $2$ to $1.4$ ! I know : it seems contradictory, and even incredible. Diluting an acidic solution with a non-acidic solution produces a more concentrated acidic solution. Personally when I read about this experiment a long time ago, I would not believe it. So I tried it at home, with a glass electrode, or an indicator. And I had to believe what I saw. The pH decreases by adding $\ce{NaCl}$. It even decreases more by adding a concentrated $\ce{CaCl_2}$ solution.

This cannot be explained by usual application of any Henderson-Hasselbach equation. It is only a question of activity. Remember that the pH is **not** minus the logarithm of the concentration of $\ce{H^+}$. No ! It is the logarithm of the activity of $\ce{H+}$. And the activity depends on the ionic strength, which depends on the concentration of **all** substances in solution.

It looks as if the activity could be considered as the number of moles divided by the volume of the "free water", if you admit that the ions $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ can "catch" or "capture" a lot of water molecules in their Debye layers, so that there is practically no more water as solvant in the solution. I have said "as if". As if !

Comment: The glass electrode is sensitive to sodium ion as well as hydrogen ion. Under the conditions of this experiment, there is a large excess of sodium ion, so the glass electrode does not accurately measure the actual pH.

Comment: So all that is necessary is to change the ionic strength by using something that does *not* significantly interfere with the pH electrode’s performance.

Comment: "[The pH] decreases even more by adding $\ce{CaCl2}$ solution".  This would seem to point to a real water-activity related effect.

Comment: @ iad22agp. Of course the glass electrode is sensitive to sodium ions. But this change of pH could also be checked by using indicators like thymol blue, whose color changes between 1,2 and 2.8. And the effect happens with CaCl2.